# com.apple.AppleJavaExtensions AboutHandler class not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to compile my java project with maven, but every time i got this error:

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project tts: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/stefano/Programming/git/DyslexoTTS/src/main/java/io/dyslexo/graphics/Tray.java:[3,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class AboutHandler
[ERROR]   location: package com.apple.eawt
```

On intelliJ I have no issues, why maven does not work?
Here the piece of code:

```
    Application application = Application.getApplication();
application.setAboutHandler(e -> {
    //my code 
});
```

I also tried to compile on different platforms like linux and windows, but i got the same error.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried to compile on different platforms like linux and windows,
>   but i got the same error. How can I fix that?

You'll have to add a stub library since those classes aren't available on non-Mac platforms.  [AppleJavaExtensions](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/AppleJavaExtensions/Introduction/Intro.html) is one example.  Put it in your compilation classpath, but be sure not to include it in the final product, assuming those classes will be available runtime.

Comment: I already added to pom.xml of the project AppleJavaExtensions' dependencies. If I compile under all platforms i get that error